# how to use date_select(rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have form, and date_select there

here is my form (in edit view)

```
=form_for @user do |f|
  %p
    = f.date_select('user','birthday',:start_year => 1940)
```

here is my edit action

```
def edit
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
 end
```

in my case it writes an error

> undefined method `merge' for "birthday":String

i have attribute birthday:date, also i tryed on string attribute but it didnt work. So how to use date select in my case?(also how to validate it? and how to set default values?)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't need to add the argument for the user, it is already contained in the `f` variable.

```
=form_for @user do |f|
  %p
    = f.date_select(:birthday,:start_year => 1940)
```

Comment: how to set default value in date_select?

Comment: The date used for the select is taken from the user, so will need to be set in the controller when @user is initialized. See here for an example: https://gist.github.com/1330389